# How to use SassC on OSX

Tags: macos, sass, terminal

I have used sass before and it's great.  But Slow. And ruby Sass is being dropped.

I'd like to swtich to a wrapper around libsass.  I think that is the accepted upgrade path.

How do I do this?  I've tried installing SassC via homebrew, but it doesn't seem to work the same way.

eg

```
sassc  --watch scss:css --style compressed
```

fails with error, unrecognized option `--watch'

What do I need to do to get sass compilation working in the terminal using libsass?

Comment: sassc scss/site.scss > css/site.css works, but nothing is imported, only sends the css in the site.scss to site.css, ignoring imports

Answer (score 0):

There was a [discussion](https://github.com/sass/sassc/issues/63) in the issue section of this project. It is not implemented and nobody was working on it according to this thread. But several workarounds were posted (e.g. using fswatch or node-sass). One suggestion was to use [gosass](https://github.com/dailymuse/gosass) which looks quite young but supports your **-watch** option.

Maybe this is something for you. If not you will find probably a lot of wrappers for libsass out there.

Comment: Finding implementations certainly isn't the issue! It's working out which one and how to get them working. : )

Comment: Your question title says "How to use SassC on OSX". Sorry if I didn't get the point of your question but because of that I had the impression you want to know how to get this working with SaasC.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.  The official implementation for command lines seems to be dart.  installing that and running  sass  --watch scss:css --style compressed  works, once ruby sass has been completely uninstalled from all rbenv rubies.  which is annoying when swtching back to rails work.  Hopefully that will be smoother when rails is off ruby-sass